# Defining function for any array of integers

Tags: arrays, function, types, julia

I want to define a function that takes as an input any array of dimension 2 that has integers (and only integers) as its elements. Although I know I don't have to specify the type of the arguments of a function in Julia, I would like to do it in order to speed it up.

With the type hierarchy, I can do this for a function that takes integers as input with the following code:

```
julia> function sum_two(x::Integer)
           return x+2
       end
sum_two (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sum_two(Int8(4))
6

julia> sum_two(Int16(4))
```

However, when I try to this for the type `Array{Integer,2}` I get the following error:

```
julia> function sum_array(x::Array{Integer,2})
           return sum(x)
       end
sum_array (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sum_array(ones(Int8,10,10))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching sum_array(::Array{Int8,2})
Closest candidates are:
  sum_array(::Array{Integer,2}) at REPL[4]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I don't what I could do to solve this. One option would be to define the method for every lowest-level subtype of Integer in the following way:

```
function sum_array(x::Array{Int8,2})
           return sum(x)
       end

function sum_array(x::Array{UInt8,2})
           return sum(x)
       end
.
.
.
```

But it doesn't look very practical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: specifying the types of input arguments to a function does *not* speed up the code. This is a misunderstanding. You should specify concrete field types when you define structs, but for function signatures it makes *no difference whatsoever* to performance. You use it to control dispatch.

Now, to your question: Julia's type parameters are invariant, meaning that even if `S<:T` is true, `A{S}<:A{T}` is *not* true. You can read more about that here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Parametric-Composite-Types-1

Therefore, `ones(Int8,10,10)`, which is a `Matrix{Int8}` is *not* a subtype of `Matrix{Integer}`.

To get your code to work, you can do this:

```
function sum_array(x::Array{T, 2}) where {T<:Integer}
    return sum(x)
end
```

or use this nice shortcut

```
function sum_array(x::Array{<:Integer, 2})
    return sum(x)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concrete reply.

Comment: If you find that the answer solves your problem, you can accept it, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers